# http://localhost prompts (save a file)

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I'm installing a local server separately components
Apache is installed,
After installing and configuring php, i type http:/localhost/index.php
It prompts me to save a file, rather that executing the php file

Comment: can be an ,htacess file issue

Comment: You've misconfigured something. Nobody else can tell. Only you have access to your setup, or know what exact steps lead to there. If you don't know how to set it up, really, just use a prepackaged Apache+PHP installer.